# Java : how to communicate from localhost Java desktop application to Java Applet?

Tags: java, applet, cross-domain, desktop-application, reverse-ajax

I would know if there is a way to make a Java desktop application to communicate with an applet, in order to call Javascript functions from the desktop app (through applet).

**The context :**

In one hand, I'm having an ExtJS application (full-AJAX), which is located on a remote server.
In the other hand, a desktop Java application (netbeans application), which is resident (indeed).

**What I would do :**

Each time one of the apps is used, it sends events & data to the other app.

After a few research, I saw interesting posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519741/how-can-a-desktop-application-communicate-with-a-web-application) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278626/javascript-to-java-applet-communication), and also an answer on [how to communicate between applets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622377/inter-applet-communication) (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341692/how-to-share-data-between-applets-in-the-same-web-page)).

The question is not about how to do cross-domain from the applet to the destktop app (see [over there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908083/java-and-crossdomain-xml) and [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2008/05/28/java-doodle-crossdomainxml-support)), but as said in the beginning how to communicate from a desktop java app to the javascript.

**Notes**

The webapp (ExtJS) is based on a remote server, the applet too. I can locate the applet locally, but it implies to deploy a local webserver.

The desktop app is very heavy, so I cannot convert it in an applet format.

I put the "reverse-AJAX" tag because it is the global concept of what I would do.

If all this is possible without an applet (*no Flash please*), it's okay too.

Comment: To call javascript from the browser applet you need to use `LiveConnect`. In order to 'fire events' from the desktop app to the applet the applet would need to connect to the desktop app using a `ServerSocket` and you need to come up with a protocol for event transfer.

Comment: @bmorris591 Seems to be the good way, thanks ! Could you please make it an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to call javascript methods from a Java applet in a browser you need to use the Netscape [LiveConnect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LiveConnect) API, there are some examples [here](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/applet/liveconnect-the-api-for-communication-between-java-applet-and-javascript).
Basically this is an API that is implemented natively by the browser and allowed a java applet to access the javascript engine of the browser.

Once you have that sorted then you need to call methods in applet from the desktop application, this is a little more tricky. The most easy way would probably be to have an `Enum` that you exchange serialised instances of to describe the type of event.

There is an example of using sockets for communication [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html).

Comment: OK Thanks for the answer and links. You got it :)